mismatched character '\n' expecting '"'
I have this code for indicator, but it shows this error

mismatched character '\n' expecting '"' in line no 3

//@version=5
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/ // Sajid Khan Ghori
indicator (title="Volume Analysis', shorttitle= 'Relative Volume [ND]', overlay=false)
length1 input.int (14, minval-1, title= 'SMA length')
SMA88 plot(ta.sma (volume, length1) 0.5, color-color.new(color.teal, 75), style-plot.style_area, title= 'Lowest SMA') SMA13 plot(ta.sma (volume, length1) 1.9, color-color.new(color.green, 75), linewidth=1, title= 'Middle SMA') SMA18 plot(ta.sma (volume, length1) 2.2, color-color.new(color.red, 75), linewidth=1, title= 'High SMA") SMA3 plot(ta.sma (volume, length1) 3.5, color-color.new(color.purple, 75), linewidth=1, title= 'Highest SMA')
x = SMA3
fill(SMA13, SMA08, color-color.new(#0965f5, 81)) fill(SMA13, SMA18, color-color.new(#ffcdd2, 61)) fill(SMA3, SMA18, color-color.new(#e57373, 39))
I
colorx = volume < volume [1] and volume < volume [2] ? #f321cb: (volume > volume [1] or volume > volume [2]) and open < close color.blue: (volume > volume [1] or volume > volume [2]) and open close color.red: color.black
SMALong
plot(ta.sma (volume, length1), style-plot.style_line, color-color.new(color.black, 0), linewidth=2, title= 'MA line') SMABody plot (volume, style-plot.style_histogram, linewidth=4, color-colorx, title= 'VOLUME', transp=0)

How can I fix this?

Get rid of the \n and replace it with "?

In line 3 as indicated by the error, you have an opening ' but have closed it with a "..
title= 'High SMA")

This should be changed to
title= 'High SMA')

